# What does native aspect ratio mean in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]
What does the word ***native*** means here? What aspect ratio will be set if I choose native aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

Native aspect ratio means that your game will always be rendered on the native (natural) resolution of the device. For example, an iPhone 6S Plus has a native resolution of 1920 x 1080, meanwhile an iPad Pro has a resolution of 2224 x 1668. If you choose native resolution and build for iOS, the resolution will be different between devices with different resolutions.

Comment: I have an android device with super ultra wide screen (1080 x 2340). Aspect ratio is around 2.1 ... If I set native aspect ratio then I get black bar at the bottom whereas if I set 2.1 it works fine....what could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. It may be a bug from Unity's side or they may simply not support your aspect ratio, which is actually rare.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think it means that you can either set your custom resolution for every device or native resolution i.e. the resolution that is available on the device.